# cannot access files on external hard drive

Tags: external-hdd

I want to access my external hard drive from the terminal. When I type :

```
    sudo lshw -C disk
[sudo] password for amit: 
  *-disk                    
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: Fuel
       vendor: LaCie
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       version: 780B
       serial: 16531405257012FX
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=b973dac0-fd31-425f-8c29-ccc5ae0e028e logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
    sudo lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop1       squashfs                                            /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
loop2       squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop3       squashfs                                            /snap/core/5742
loop4       squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop5       squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop6       squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
sda                                                             
└─sda1      ntfs     DATA  0E023D2D023D1AE3                     
sdb                                                             
└─sdb1      vfat     AMIT  C91D-0871                            /media/amit/AMIT
sdc                                                             
├─sdc1                                                          
└─sdc2      exfat    LaCie 68E1-45CA                            
nvme0n1                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat           83B0-67FC                            /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4           1c7d6070-763e-492f-a650-64eb320ed2e6 /
└─nvme0n1p3 swap           1cc42521-b494-4bbd-a32f-e0ef1e333953 [SWAP]

amit@amit-X705UDR:/$ mount|grep '^/dev'
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/amit/AMIT type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)



sudo lsblk -m
NAME          SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0        14,5M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop1        42,1M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop2         2,3M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop3        87,9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop4          13M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop5       140,7M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop6         3,7M root  disk  brw-rw----
sda         931,5G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1      931,5G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb         231,9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1      231,9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdc           1,8T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdc1        128M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdc2        1,8T root  disk  brw-rw----
nvme0n1     465,8G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p1   512M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─nvme0n1p2 433,4G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─nvme0n1p3  31,9G root  disk  brw-rw---
```

I remember there was a library or a program in Ubuntu which could be installed to do the needful to access the files.I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
Can someone help !

Comment: Please tell us about the partition(s) and file system(s) on the external hard disk drive. For example, you can edit your original question to show the output of the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `mount|grep '^/dev'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/dev/sdc is a DISK
a disk, to store files, needs PARTITIONS
please fire up program called gparted (or install it with apt-get install gparted) and make sure the partitions are available. if there are none, create one. ext4 is going to be fine (or NTFS if you plan to use the disk with multiple operating systems)
If there ARE partitions on this disk, please let us know what kind of partition is it, then we can suggest what to do to access them.

after question EDIT: now we can see the partition is there and it's exfat.
Please install 
`sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`
and reconnect the drive (or reboot)